# Periodic "Opening tables" on MySQL Insert

Tags: mysql

I have a long-running insert that shows a status that toggles between "NULL" and "Opening tables"

```
|  5 | mckelvey | mushroom.jpl.nasa.gov:57050 | smap_ampcs_v5_2_0 | Query   | 7105 | Opening tables | INSERT INTO ChannelValue

|  5 | mckelvey | mushroom.jpl.nasa.gov:57050 | smap_ampcs_v5_2_0 | Query   | 7114 | NULL  | INSERT INTO ChannelValue
```

It does this continually. Show open tables shows 10 opened tables, 5 in use.
Global status "Opened_tables" is 190 and does not increase. table_open_cache is 1024.

Is something wrong? Why does it constantly open tables for an insert already in progress?

The insert is below. The tables in the v4 database are MyISAM, and v5_2 are InnoDB. ComboParent is temporary and MyISAM. No errors in the server log.

```
INSERT INTO ChannelValue
     SELECT
         cv.sessionId,
         cv.hostId,
         cv.sessionFragment,
         1 AS id,
         cv.id AS channelDataId,
         cp.parentId,
         NULL AS uniqueId,
         IF (cv.dnUnsignedValue IS NOT NULL,
             CONVERT(cv.dnUnsignedValue, SIGNED),
             cv.dnIntegerValue) AS dnPackedValue,
         cv.dnDoubleValue,
         sv.stringId,
         cv.eu,
         SET_FLAGS(cv.dnDoubleFlag,
                   cv.euFlag,
                   cv.dnAlarmState,
                   cv.euAlarmState,
                   cv.dnUnsignedValue) AS flags
    FROM smap_ampcs_v4_0_0.ChannelValue AS cv
    STRAIGHT_JOIN ComboParent AS cp
    ON ((cv.sessionId       = cp.sessionId)       AND
        (cv.hostId          = cp.hostId)          AND
        (cv.sessionFragment = cp.sessionFragment) AND
        (cv.sclkCoarse      = cp.sclkCoarse)      AND
        (cv.sclkFine        = cp.sclkFine)        AND
        (cv.ertCoarse       = cp.ertCoarse)       AND
        (cv.ertFine         = cp.ertFine)         AND
        (cv.scetCoarse      = cp.scetCoarse)      AND
        (cv.scetFine        = cp.scetFine)        AND
        (cv.dssId           = cp.dssId)           AND
        (cv.vcid            <=> cp.vcid)          AND
        (cv.isRealtime      = cp.isRealtime))
    LEFT JOIN StringValue AS sv
    ON (
        (cv.hostId          = sv.hostId)          AND
        (cv.sessionId       = sv.sessionId)       AND
        (cv.sessionFragment = sv.sessionFragment) AND
        (0                  = sv.fromSse)         AND
        (cv.dnStringValue   = sv.stringValue)
       )
    WHERE (cv.packetId IS NULL)
```

Comment: This is a Microsoft SQL Server forum not MySQL which despite the common letters SQL are very different products.

Comment: The host is dedicated ti MySQL.